# TFS: which structure to setup one project with different, isolated customers?

Tags: team-foundation-server

What's the best structure to setup a Project in the TFS 2015 or 2017 for one Product which is acessed by 1 Development-Team and different customers? We should have:

1 Code-Repository
» … for 1 Product which is in development
» … which is accessed by 1 Developer-Team
» … which is accessed by **multipe, isolated Customers** for bugs & requirements

In other words: we have one single codebase which is shared by all customers (it is the same product for each customer), but they have different their own bug-, feature-, … Tasks.

The TFS structure should offer:

- One Code Repository for all customers
- every Customer can create and see **his own** Tasks, Issues, Bugs, ...
- It should be possible to assign Issues, Tasks, etc. to the Development-Team from all Customers and to assign those items to code-commits, too.

Is it possible to isolate those customers and handle their requests by one Team?

Thanks a lot for any Help, Link, Tipp...

Comment: Hi Sven, just because a Team Foundation Server is a Development System does not mean that there are no questions about managing it. In my question, I ask for the Server Management.
But if you're sure this question is wrong here, then I'm happy to move it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to stay with a single Project and use Areas security to limit visibility on data (see [Set permissions to restrict access to work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations#set-permissions-to-restrict-access-to-work-items)). You should setup a proper security structure with a group per each customer and grant permission to the respective area.
It will be up to the dev team to assign the Area to the work item (task,bug,etc.).

Furthermore the group should be 
[Work as a stakeholder](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/work-as-a-stakeholder) otherwise these user needs a proper CAL.

Final step is to allow connection to your on-premise TFS, which means properly configuring SSL -- very easy on 2017, [more laborious on 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer) -- and configuring external access by opening your firewall or configuring a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thank your very much, Giulio Vian, for your fast and clear answer! At least, I think I know what we have to do :-) Kind regards, Thomas